# C# 2008 Express v C# 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

Can anybody post a link to a comparison chart, or even to a duplicated question here on SO, for these two products?

Plenty of info on what is missing between Express and Pro for example, but I'm struggling to find much on Express v Express.

Is the only real difference the ability to develop apps for .NET 4.0?

I'm developing WinForms apps, targetting .NET 2.0 at the moment, so are there any benefits for me in changing to 2010 Express?

Unfortunately, upgrading to VS Professional or such is not an option for me right now, so I'm stuck with the hamstrung versions.

eThanks.

Comment: Since the Express are available for free, you could always just install both the 2008 and 2010 editions and compare or yourself!

Comment: to add on what stakx said, you might as well go for 2010 Express, although its catered for .NET 4.0 its still going to be backwards compatible, 1.0,2.0,3.5 etc - plus by the time your read to transition from 2010 Express to Visual Studio Pro 2010 the interface will be very similar, easier to adjust to.

Comment: @stakx & Dal: Yes, fair point, I can go ahead and just try it. Just wondered if there was a definitive list somewhere. As for upgrading to Pro, that would depend if I can ever break open my boss's wallet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bottom line first:

If you're developing against the .NET Framework version 2.0, and especially with WinForms instead of WPF, **chances are that you're not going to profit much** from an upgrade to VS 2010.

---

### My very brief comparison list:

I have three versions of Visual Studio installed: 2008 Express (C# and VB.NET), 2008 Standard, and 2010 Express (C# only). (That is, you can install both Express editions without side-effects and compare for yourself!)

- Of those, I prefer the VS 2008 Express edition for rapid development and code experiments, not least because it has very quick **start-up time**. VS 2010 takes longer to start.
- VS 2010 has a new **look-and-feel** to it. You may or may not like it better than VS 2008's look. I seem to remember that they also made slight improvements to IntelliSense.
- VS 2010 Express seems to allow certain **extensions** (Extension Manager). I'm not quite sure whether this allows more plug-ins than was possible in VS 2008 Express.
- <strike>VS 2010 Express</strike> .NET 4.0 has **[Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/) built-in**. With VS 2008 Express, you cannot <strike>use</strike> install this library as an add-on (unless you have a commercial VS edition installed, too). But probably this is not an issue; you can always use a unit testing framework like [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) instead.

As you can tell, the above comparison list is rather short and uncertain. This is due to the fact that I've largely stayed with VS 2008 Express, although I have other editions installed, too.

---

### Possible reasons for an upgrade:

The only reasons I can think of where VS 2008 Express is not enough is that you either want to:

- use VS plug-ins (e.g. [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html), or [Code Contracts](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/)); or
- use libraries that at least partly require the .NET 4.0 framework (e.g. [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/)).

Comment: On the Code Contracts front - could you clarify? .NET 4.0 has Code Contracts built in, but *none* of the Visual Studio editions has the tools built in; you always need to download the tools separately. I don't know if the CC tools even work with VS Express, as the Express editions usually don't do plug-ins...

Comment: _@Jon Skeet:_ You're right (I edited my post accordingly). But as far as I can remember, with VS 2008 Express you simply had *no possibility* of compiling source code that referenced the Code Contracts library, because you could not *install* that library without having at least a Standard edition of VS installed.

Comment: VS2010 express does *not* let you install plug-ins like Resharper.  The only thing you can install in the express editions via the extension manager are templates.

Comment: *@Noah Richards:* Thanks for the info. That's exactly what I did so far concerning extensions; I wasn't certain from experience if it allowed anything more than that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing WinForms application and targeting .NET 2.0 the only benefit I can see in upgrading to VS2010 Express is performance improvements (new WPF code editor), maybe few bug fixes and prepare your project for future upgrades to .NET.

Comment: Thanks Darin, pretty much what I suspected.

Answer (score 1):

For a vanilla 2.0 Webforms app I'd have to say nothing truly groundbreaking, but 2010 does support multiple monitors which is nice.

On the other hand, upgrading should be quite painless.